# Execute a query build by a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

in a procedure, I start by building a query (an union of select) with some datas in a  DB.
Then I want to put the result of the query in a file but when I try to use
`execute immediate` or `dbms_sql.execute` follow by my query that I build, nothing happened.

So I was wondering, how to execute such a query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SPOOL TEST.TXT

DECLARE
   test_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
   v_date     DATE;
BEGIN
   OPEN test_cur FOR 'SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL';

   FETCH test_cur INTO   v_date;

   CLOSE test_cur;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('DATE IS ' || v_date);
END;

SPOOL OFF

DATE IS 11-DEC-12
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

OR DIRECTLY WITHOUT PLSQL BLOCK

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SPOOL TEST.TXT
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
SPOOL OFF

SYSDATE  
---------
11-DEC-12
1 row selected.
```

**EDIT**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SPOOL TEST.TXT

DECLARE
  CURSOR  test_cur   
   IS SELECT * FROM XYZ;
BEGIN
   FOR v_test_row IN test_cur;
   LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('XXXYYYY ' || v_test_row .<your column name>);
   END LOOP;

END;

SPOOL OFF
```

Comment: I don't know the type of the field I get, so I can't use this method I guess ?

Answer (score 1):

When executing queries from a client like SQL*Plus is easy to forget that in the background the client program opens a cursor and loops fetching each row.
In PL/SQL you have to do the same:

- open a cursor (open)
- loop

  - fetch a row into a variable
  - exit when no more rows
  - do whatever with the variable
- end loop

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I tried this :  `for v in (select * from bcn_requete) loop
  dbms_output.put_line(v.id);
 end LOOP; ` It works but if the query is inside a variable, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: See Gaurav's answer above. It describes in detail what I summarized.

Comment: @jacen44: for your statement,you need to create cursor first in declaration part `CURSOR bcn_cur IS select * from bcn_requete; ` and then use that cursor in for loop as shown  `for v in bcn_cur `